# Service Tomcat disappeared from services list

Tags: tomcat, service, windows-services, hippocms

I have Apache Tomcat 7 installed on Windows 7. I had its service in Services, I could start/stop it there.

Today **I installed Hippo CMS** from http://www.onehippo.com/en/products/cms/try (section "Download Hippo CMS"). It installed itself in `C:/Program files/Hippo`. I realized that it is bundle with Tomcat inside itself. Then I uninstalled Hippo and... **Apache Tomcat disappeared from Services!**

I think the uninstaller removed it thinking it was its own Tomcat. My usual Tomcat folders are still at their place. I tried

- browsing to the usual localhost:8080.. nothing
- restarting my PC.. nothing
- running `tomcat7.exe` and `tomcat7w.exe` from `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin`.. nothing

I'm thinking about reinstalling Tomcat.. any other idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try service.bat in /bin directory of tomcat.

I advise you to reinstall Tomcat, its faster than trying to recover.